# enable a textbox on the selection of no from the drop down menu

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down menu where i have three options yes no and later.And when i select no option then the textbox must enable which was previously disable.so help me with some javascript script and explain me how can i call the script from the form.

Comment: Would you please post the minimum html and the minimum JavaScript that you have now? Or the URL of the page? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `onchange` event and check for the value of the option elements, something like this:

```
mySelect.onchange = function () {
    document.getElementById("myTextArea").disabled = this.value != "No";
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zJ97A/**

Answer (score 0):

Here you go : http://jsfiddle.net/neebz/LcfN5/

However I would strongly suggest you use a framework like jQuery or something for cross-browser compatibility.